# React Native: Add opacity to text at the bottom of scrollview

Tags: javascript, react-native, text, scrollview

Do you guys have any idea how to achieve this? The text is wrapped in ScrollView with maxHeight 400.

```
 <ScrollView style={{maxHeight: 400}}>
   <Text>{text}</Text>
 </ScrollView>
```

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried adding opacity to the bottom text?

Comment: No, the text is coming from the API. I updated the description.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you :

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={"row"}
    onPress={() => {
        onClick(params)
    }}>
    <View>
        <Text>1</Text>
        <Text>2</Text>
        <Text>4</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And here is live demo : https://snack.expo.io/@maifeeulasad/delicious-marshmallows

Comment: Isn't this incorrect? It will add opacity only on press. OP wants the text to have permanent opacity.

Comment: @Rohit please check out, I;ve added live demo... if I'm getting the question right, then my solution is absolutely correct... i think so... and the demo says so...